# Determine whether this series converges using ratio test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Umgh...
I just have no idea, srsly, I've never done anything  with sum of products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th term is $$a_n=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}.$$ The ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is the following: $$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}}=\frac{3(n+1)-1}{4(n+1)-3}=\frac{3n+2}{4n+1}$$ I was able to cancel many terms because these are products. The limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ tends to $3/4 < 1$

Comment: although it is obvious you would need to show $(3n-1)/(4n-1)$ is increasing

Comment: Yup, you're right, and that can be shown quite easily using derivatives for instance.

Comment: @user142634 Why would you need to show that the fraction is increasing?

Comment: @Johan ratio test says every fraction should be less than 1 so  when n increases if the fraction increases then only we can say that every fraction is less than 3/4 ,if fraction decreases then we can say every fraction is greater than 3/4 and if no order observed then we cannot say anything.

Comment: @user142634, if the limit is $3/4$ then the fractions will be less than $1$ for large enough $n$. The limit suffices, no need to know how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of two consecutive terms has the form
$$
\frac{3n-1}{4n-1} \to \frac34
$$
Since $\frac34\ne1$, the ratio test concludes.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an approach to this problem since you wrote "*I've never done anything with sum of products*".

You are asked about $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}$$ Rewrite it as $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$ with $$a_n=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{3j-1}{4j-3}$$ This bring you to a classical form (analyze the behavior of $a_n$ and conclude about the convergence of $S$). As already said in answers and comments $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3 n+2}{4 n+1}$$

May be, you could be interested to know that $S=13.2047328961513\cdots$.